# Correct data type passed to barplot

Tags: r, plot

My initial goal was to set `ylim` for data plotted by `barplot`. When I started to dig deeper I've found several things that I do not understand. Let me explain my research:

I have 1D vector:

```
> str(vectorName)
 num [1:999] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

> dim(vectorName)
NULL

> length(vectorName)
[1] 999
```

If I want to count the particular elements of this vector I do:

```
> vectorNameTable = table(vectorName)
> vectorNameTable
vectorName
    0 0.025  0.05 0.075   0.1 0.125  0.15 0.175   0.2 0.225  0.25 0.275   0.3 0.325  0.35 0.375   0.4 
  563    72    35    22    14    21    14    10     5     3     7     3     6     5     3     1     3 
0.425  0.45 0.475   0.5 0.525  0.55 0.575   0.6 0.625  0.65 0.675   0.7 0.725  0.75 0.775   0.8 0.825 
    1     3     3     5     7    11     3     4     3    11     5     9     5     7     8     5     3 
 0.85 0.875   0.9 0.925 0.975     1 
    3     4     2     1     1   108
```

This is how I display those data more elegant way (in R-studio):

```
> View(vectorNameTable)
```

Which gives me output like this:

```
    vectorName  Freq
1   0       563
2   0.025   72
3   0.05    35
4   0.075   22
5   0.1     14
6   0.125   21
7   0.15    14
8   0.175   10
9   0.2     5
10  0.225   3
11  0.25    7
12  0.275   3
13  0.3     6
14  0.325   5
15  0.35    3
16  0.375   1
17  0.4     3
18  0.425   1
19  0.45    3
20  0.475   3
21  0.5     5
22  0.525   7
23  0.55    11
24  0.575   3
25  0.6     4
26  0.625   3
27  0.65    11
28  0.675   5
29  0.7     9
30  0.725   5
31  0.75    7
32  0.775   8
33  0.8     5
34  0.825   3
35  0.85    3
36  0.875   4
37  0.9     2
38  0.925   1
39  0.975   1
40  1       108
```

If I want to plot this data I do:

```
> barplot(vectorNameTable)
```

Which gives me this plot:

[image]

As you can see 0 is occurring more times than is y-axis size. So what I want is to set the size of y-axis using:

`barplot(table(vectorNameTable), ylim=c(0,MAX_VALUE_IN_FREQ_COLUMN))`

The problem is that I cannot find the largest value in `Freq` column. To be more precise I cannot even access the `Freq` column. I've tried:

```
> vectorNameTable[,1]
Error in vectorNameTable[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

and several other attempts, but seems that the only thing that I am able to obtain is whole row:

```
> vectorNameTable[1]
  0 
563 
> vectorNameTable[2]
0.025 
   72
```

Or even the `Freq` value in given row:

```
> vectorNameTable[[1]]
[1] 563
> vectorNameTable[[2]]
[1] 72
```

The one possible workaround that is working is converting the data to matrix:

```
vectorNameDF = data.frame(vectorNameTable)
val = vectorNameDF[[1]]
frq = vectorNameDF[[2]]
val = as.numeric(levels(val))
vectorNameMTX = matrix(c(val, frq), nrow=length(val))
```

Then I cand do something like this:

```
barplot(vectorNameTable, ylim=c(0,max(vectorNameMTX[,2])+50))
```

Which will return:
[image]

But as you can see it is extreme overkill. Another mysterious thing that I've found is that plotting the graph this way (same as `barplot(vectorNameMTX, beside=FALSE)`):

```
> barplot(vectorNameMTX)
```

Will return this:

[image]

This command `> barplot(vectorNameMTX, beside=TRUE)` will return this:
[image]

Why this is happening? I mean what is this "line" on the left? And where is x-axis? If I do `View(vectorNameMTX)` it returns very similar table to `View(vectorNameTable)`. The documentation for `barplot` says (only important things):

```
Bar Plots

Description

Creates a bar plot with vertical or horizontal bars.

Usage

barplot(height, ...)

height  
either a vector or matrix of values describing the bars which make up the plot. If height is a vector, the plot consists of a sequence of rectangular bars with heights given by the values in the vector. If height is a matrix and beside is FALSE then each bar of the plot corresponds to a column of height, with the values in the column giving the heights of stacked sub-bars making up the bar. If height is a matrix and beside is TRUE, then the values in each column are juxtaposed rather than stacked.
```

I'm passing the matrix, but it does not working as expected:

```
> class(vectorNameMTX)
[1] "matrix"
```

On the other hand this one is not mentioned as supported type but it is working:

```
> class(vectorNameTable)
[1] "table"
```

Why I can't access columns of `vectorNameTable`? Why is passing the table object working while passing an matrix is not? What I'm missing here and what is the best way to achieve my goal?

Thank you

Comment: This is a really long question.  Any chance you could condense it down to the minimum viable example?  When you say "why is this happening," I'm not even clear what *this* **is**

Comment: I would split this into 2 questions: a) max of a table; b) barplot misbehaving

Comment: R tables have values and often (as is the case here) an attribute called "names". The `View` function is showing those "names" as the leftmost "column".  To use the "names" "column" you would apply the .... wait for it .... `names`-function. If you convert to a single column dataframe, those names would no longer be in the attribute called "names" but would now be the dataframe's "rownames" also stored as an attribute.

Comment: First - you probably don't want to use `table` on a continuous variable, your data looks a bit like frequency spectra and I guess you want a histogram of the frequency spectra. Second - look into `ggplot` for more convenient plotting - `ggplot(data.frame(freq=vectorName), aes(freq)) + geom_histogram()`.

Answer (score 0):

Table of a 1d vector is a 1d vector, so there is no columns.  You can do something like

```
 > a <- rbinom(1000, 25, 0.5)
 > tb <- table(a)
 > tb
 a
  6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20 
  8  20  31  71  96 155 141 146 136  94  46  33  15   7   1 
 > dim(tb)
 [1] 15 # 1 dimension of 15
 > tb[which.max(tb)]
 11 
 155
```

So you can feed this max value to barplot.